# Map object inside an mapped object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops, material-ui

I'm trying to map an array inside an already mapped array

My goal is to show the `userName` and `products` each user has.

First I map the `data` array and display the `userName` of each object. Then I try to display each product within the same object.

This is my attempt

```
{
    this.state.orders.map((item, index) =>{
      return <div key={index}>
        <ListItem button onClick={()=>{this.handleClick('order1')}}>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <InboxIcon />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText inset primary={item.userName}  secondary={item.order[0].product}/>
          {this.state.order1Open  ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
           <AddIcon />
         </ListItem>
         <Collapse in={this.state.order1Open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
           <List component="div" disablePadding>
             { item.order.map((products, index) =>{
               {console.log('product',products.product)}
                  <ListItem key={index} button className={classes.nested}>
                    <ListItemIcon>
                      <StarBorder />
                    </ListItemIcon>
                    <ListItemText inset primary={console.log(products.product)} />            
                  </ListItem>
                }  
              )}
```

The result is that the username gets displayed but the products don't

When I `console.log('product',products.product)}`

My response are my products

example:

```
product product1
product product2
product product3
product product4
product product5
```

So this confirms that the `order` object indeed gets mapped, but doesn't display the information inside the `collapse` => `list` => `listItem`. I'ts just empty

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Data feed and objects

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "code":1,
         "userId":1,
         "userName":"Jerome Lebanner",
         "timeStamp":"01:00 07-04-2019",
         "order":[
            {
               "item":"product",
               "price":2.5,
               "qty":3
            },
            {
               "drink":"product",
               "price":5.5,
               "qty":3
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":1,
         "code":2,
         "userId":1,
         "userName":"Claudia Schommels",
         "timeStamp":"01:00 07-04-2019",
         "order":[
            {
               "item":"product",
               "price":2.5,
               "qty":2
            },
            {
               "item":"product",
               "price":5.5,
               "qty":3
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":1,
         "code":3,
         "userId":1,
         "userName":"LadiesChaser87",
         "timeStamp":"01:00 07-04-2019",
         "order":[
            {
               "item":"product",
               "price":4.5,
               "qty":1
            },
            {
               "item":"product",
               "price":5.5,
               "qty":3
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Why do you do this `primary={console.log(products.product)}` in the `<ListItemText>` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the HTML like this:

```
{ item.order.map((products, index) =>{
    {console.log('product',products.product)}
    return (<ListItem key={index} button className={classes.nested}>
      <ListItemIcon>
        <StarBorder />
      </ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText inset primary={console.log(products.product)} />            
    </ListItem>);
  }  
)}
```

Comment: I'm a fool. Forgot to `return`